# Oracle 12c SQL Random String Digits Only Size 10

Tags: sql, oracle, random

what's the easiest way to get a 10 character random string containing only numeric characters (digits)? The one below gives something similar but I would like to get strings with left padded zeros also. e.g. 0000000020

```
SELECT LPAD(REPLACE(TO_CHAR(dbms_random.value(1, 9999999999)),'.',''),10,'0') randomnumstr 
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: Have a look at https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2015/12/a-random-string-of-digits/ if it helps you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break it down in pieces...

```
select to_char(dbms_random.value(1, 10000000000), 'FM0000000000') from dual;
```

First, the `dbms_random.value` will return a number in the range [a,b), so use 1 as the start and 10000000000 as the end. The number will never equal 10000000000.

Second, use `TO_CHAR` with a mask of `FM0000000000`. The `FM` removes the padding added for the sign. By not including a decimal point, the fractional portion of the random number is truncated.

[DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_random.htm#TTPLP71247)

Now test a few literals to make sure it works:

```
select to_char(1.234, 'FM0000000000') from dual;

0000000001

select to_char(1234, 'FM0000000000') from dual;

0000001234

select to_char(1234567890, 'FM0000000000') from dual;

1234567890

-- Now make sure there are no spaces for the sign
select length(to_char(123, 'FM0000000000')) from dual;

10
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a shorter choice :

```
SELECT DECODE(val,0,val+1E-10,val) AS randomnumstr 
  FROM
  (SELECT SUBSTR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 1),-10) AS val
     FROM dual);
```

which may also contain preceding zeroes and having ten-digit-length. The `val` is generated as being greater than or equal to `0`, and strictly less than `1` (`0<=val<1`). In the case, `val` equals to `0`, then result will be `0000000001`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will not work if DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 9) returns 0, which it can, per documentation. Probably SUBSTR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 9),-10)?

Comment: Hi @blueolive . For both cases (no matter `(0,9)` or `(1,9)`), there exists probability to have `0000000000` (zeroes of ten-digit). You are right. So, I narrowed down the interval to `(0,1)`, and for the zero returning case adding `1E-10` in order to get `0000000001` instead of `0000000000`.

Comment: The string of zeros of ten digits will work for me. Thank you for taking time to answer the question, Barbaros!